# Установить часовой пояс Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

При добавлении каких-либо данных в базу, в полях типа 'created_at' отображается время, не соответствующее часовому поясу. Подскажите пожалуйста, как/где настроить часовой пояс? Заранее всем большое спасибо!

Comment: `$table->timestampsTz();` - [**TIMESTAMP (with timezone) equivalent column.**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#creating-columns)

Comment: А можно по-подробнее? Не много не ясно в каком фасаде редактировать

Comment: Хм..у меня таблица уже создана. Как быть?

Comment: А данные, которые уже есть в таблицах при этом не удалятся?

Comment: Обновил. Время создания все равно на 2 часа меньше чем надо

Comment: Покажите кусок кода с миграцией.

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('trands', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('product_id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->integer('rate');
            $table->timestampsTz();
        });
    }

Кроме этого метода больше ничего не менял

Comment: Возможно, [поможет Вам](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10661)

Comment: Ну + в настройках не забываем app.php 'timezone' => 'Europe/Moscow',

Comment: Да, я сразу же поставил

Answer (score 0):

Часовой пояс настраивается в конфигурационном файле config/app.php в поле timezone. Список поддерживаемых часовых поясов -http://php.net/manual/ru/timezones.php

Comment: В комментариях уже сказали, что этот способ не помог..

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1**
Откройте файл .env в корне вашего проекта Laravel и найдите переменную APP_TIMEZONE. Укажите нужный часовой пояс в этой переменной
APP_TIMEZONE=Europe/Moscow

**Вариант 2**
Для изменения часового пояса приложения в файле config/app.php найдите параметр 'timezone' и установите нужный часовой пояс. Например:
'timezone' => 'Europe/Moscow'

[Как установить часовой пояс в Laravel](https://nesterenko.site/post/kak-ustanovit-casovoi-poias-v-laravel)